# filter in aggregation and groupby to get values from given time interval

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

in the below `$aggregate` query, want to add a filter with `$gt` and `$lt`

The mongo doc:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599eb4fae0f86361c36b1c91"),
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5993df1b9a5fea3183064e49"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-24T11:38:12.135Z"),
    "power_data" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-08-24T11:14:04.256Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("599eb4fdeea8c69622751de3"),
            "pfactor" : 1,
            "rpower" : 0,
            "voltage" : 0,
            "current" : 0,
            "energy" : 0,
            "power" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-08-24T11:14:04.256Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("599eb507eea8c69622751de4"),
            "pfactor" : 1,
            "rpower" : 0,
            "voltage" : 0,
            "current" : 0,
            "energy" : 0,
            "power" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-08-24T11:14:04.256Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("599eb511eea8c69622751de5"),
            "pfactor" : 1,
            "rpower" : 0,
            "voltage" : 0,
            "current" : 0,
            "energy" : 0,
            "power" : 0
        }, 
 ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-24T11:14:05.946Z")
}
```

and here is the query :

```
aggregate([{
        $match: { "device_id": { $in: [ObjectId("5993df1b9a5fea3183064e49")] } }
    }, {
        $project: {
            "power_data": 1
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$power_data"
    }, 
     {     
        $project: {
           "power": "$power_data.power", "hours": { $dayOfMonth: "$power_data.timestamp" }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$hours", "avg_power": { $avg: "$power" }
        }
    }]
```

all i want is, by passing some date timestamp range, i will get the data for this time interval only, currently its calculating overall.

***Thanks For you valuable time!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to add an additional `$match` stage after the `$unwind`.

Here's the full pipeline:

```
{
    $match: { "device_id": { $in: [ObjectId("5993df1b9a5fea3183064e49")] } }
}, 
{
    $project: { "power_data": 1 }
},
{
    $unwind: "$power_data"
}, 
{
    $match: {
        "power_data.timestamp" : { $gt : ISODate("2017-08-23T12:00:00.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2017-08-25T12:00:00.000Z")}
    }
},
{     
    $project: { "power": "$power_data.power", "hours": { $dayOfMonth: "$power_data.timestamp" }
}
},
{
    $group: { "_id": "$hours", "avg_power": { $avg: "$power" } }
}
```